# Sum of digits in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sum-of-digits

What's the fastest and easiest to read implementation of calculating the sum of digits?

I.e. Given the number: 17463 = 1 + 7 + 4 + 6 + 3 = 21

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You could do it arithmetically, without using a string:

```
sum = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  This is the best way.

Comment: Personally, I see this better conceptually as a for loop... But maybe that's just my mind, I tend to see everything better as a for loop...

Comment: @monoxide, the while loop is more succinct.  You have no need for an index or for tight control of the loop iterations.

Comment: for (; n!= 0; n /= 10) { sum += n % 10;}  To my mind there's an implicit counter there, n. But my mind is known to work funilly when talking about loops. There's no need to initialise n of course, because that's handled before the loop presumably.

Comment: +1: I love this code, it's very elegant. Not new to me, but very cool.

Comment: how about is the number overflow?  % or / won't work anymore!  Try this code instead:  n.ToString().Sum( c => Convert.ToInt32(c) );

Comment: Okay, I know that % is modulus but can someone please fill me in on what on earth the `/=` means? I googled it but google does not understand what I am looking for. Thank you! EDIT: Never mind. += means add whatever is on the right to the variable on the left so /= must be the same but with division. DOH! All this time I did not know that! ( I knew you could do addition and subtraction but not division in this manner)

Comment: @JohnAugust: Although the following question is tagged [php], it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542995/what-is-used-for

Comment: Thank you very much Greg, I still cannot believe I did not know that you could do that with division and multiplication. I always thought it was just addition and subtraction.

Comment: This assumes that the `n /= 10` will be truncated to an integer. For languages such as JavaScript, use something like `n = Math.floor(n / 10)`

Comment: There are some cases that won't have reduced to a single digit by the time `n` reaches 0 (e.g. digit sum of 85 is 13). If it needs to always produce a single digit, I get around this by adding `|| sum > 9` to the while condition, and adding an if loop at the bottom (condition is `n == 0 && sum > 9`) that sets `n = sum` and `sum = 0` to restart the digit sum if it's not a single digit. Mathematically, this will always halt (there's no digit sum that will carry on producing long outputs).

Comment: Elegant approach, optimal solution, clean & short, easy to read, this is simply beautiful code.

Answer (score 52):

I use

```
int result = 17463.ToString().Sum(c => c - '0');
```

It uses only 1 line of code.

Comment: Converting an integer to a string in order to sum it's values is not really very efficient.  I also don't consider this code especially readable.  Though I didn't downvote this.

Comment: You forgot to convert the string to array first.

17463.ToString().ToCharArray().Sum(c => c - '0');

Comment: You don't have to convert it to an array first.

Comment: Very nice and functional approach!

Comment: Wouldn't this outperform the numerical approach by for for big numbers ? (Think BigInteger)

Comment: can you explain how this works? i don't understand the `- '0'`

Comment: @JocaPinto Hint: see character 0 till 9 in ASCII table.

Comment: Wow! This is the best approach in case we receive a huge number from user as string. For example string can be like "5124253541525525266263636363" and you can't read it as variable of any integer type.

Comment: If you are doing this for code golf, use 48 instead of '0'

Answer (score 19):

For integer numbers, Greg Hewgill has most of the answer, but forgets to account for the n < 0. The sum of the digits of -1234 should still be 10, not -10.

```
n = Math.Abs(n);
sum = 0;
while (n != 0) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

It the number is a floating point number, a different approach should be taken, and chaowman's solution will completely fail when it hits the decimal point.

Comment: Good catch. It all depends on how the modulo operator is defined in the language in question; in C# the result takes the same sign as the dividend which makes my method fail for negative numbers. In other languages it may work, see the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 14):

```
 public static int SumDigits(int value)
 {
     int sum = 0;
     while (value != 0)
     {
         int rem;
         value = Math.DivRem(value, 10, out rem);
         sum += rem;
     }
     return sum;
 }
```

Comment: Assuming DivRem does the intelligent thing, this should avoid doing the division twice.  I like it better than the other obvious answer (though both are close).

Comment: This is the code of DivRem
public static int DivRem(int a, int b, out int result)
{
    result = a % b;
    return (a / b);
}
 
so it does not make intelligent thing!!

Comment: Any reasonable compiler will see that x and y don't change between the x/y and x%y operations and thus can utilize a single divsion op to get both results. I know that gcc does this for c/c++ code. I assume c# compilers are at least as competent with such a simple optimization.

Comment: This almost certainly isn't something the C# compiler would do - it would be up to the JIT.

Comment: fair enough, I was kinda lumping the JIT and the compiler proper into one category, but yea, the JIT would do the actual optimization.

Answer (score 14):

```
int num = 12346;
int sum = 0;
for (int n = num; n > 0; sum += n % 10, n /= 10) ;
```

Comment: Although there are many correct answers but this should be the best and correct answer

Answer (score 3):

I like the chaowman's response, but would do one change

```
int result = 17463.ToString().Sum(c => Convert.ToInt32(c));
```

I'm not even sure the c - '0', syntax would work? (substracting two characters should give a character as a result I think?)

I think it's the most readable version (using of the word sum in combination with the lambda expression showing that you'll do it for every char). But indeed, I don't think it will be the fastest.

Comment: I come here 7 years late , but for some reason `Convert.ToInt32` returned `4 * 54 = 206` for me when I ran it with this code: `2156.ToString().Sum(c => Convert.ToInt32(c));` Any idea whats going on? c - '0' worked perfectly tho.

Comment: @kuskmen See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx ... the iterator of a string iterates over chars This invocation of ToInt32() returns a 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument.

Comment: so I guess my improvement in 2009, was not really a working improvement :-(
(So just ignore this answer)

Comment: `Math.Abs(-123).ToString().Sum(char.GetNumericValue);`

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd just post this for completion's sake:

If you need a recursive sum of digits, e.g: **17463** -> 1 + 7 + 4 + 6 + 3 = **21** -> 2 + 1 = **3**
then the best solution would be

```
int result = input % 9;
return (result == 0 && input > 0) ? 9 : result;
```

Comment: close, but should be: return (result==0 && input>0) ? 9 : result;

Answer (score 3):

```
int n = 17463; int sum = 0;
for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i / 10)
{
sum = sum + i % 10;
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the easiest to read implementation would be something like:

```
public int sum(int number)
{
    int ret = 0;
    foreach (char c in Math.Abs(number).ToString())
        ret += c - '0';
    return ret;
}
```

This works, and is quite easy to read.  BTW: Convert.ToInt32('3') gives 51, not 3.  Convert.ToInt32('3' - '0') gives 3.

I would assume that the fastest implementation is Greg Hewgill's arithmetric solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static int getDigitSum(int ds)
{
    int dssum = 0;            
    while (ds > 0)
    {
        dssum += ds % 10;
        ds /= 10;
        if (dssum > 9)
        {                
            dssum -= 9;
        }
    }
    return dssum;
}
```

This is to provide the sum of digits between 0-9

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int SumDigits1(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int rem;
    while (n != 0)
    {           
        n = Math.DivRem(n, 10, out rem);
        sum += rem;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int SumDigits2(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int rem;
    for (sum = 0; n != 0; sum += rem)   
        n = Math.DivRem(n, 10, out rem);        
    return sum;
}   

public static int SumDigits3(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;    
    while (n != 0)
    {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }   
    return sum;
}
```

Complete code in: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lwKHyA

Answer (score 0):

```
int j, k = 1234;
for(j=0;j+=k%10,k/=10;);
```

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I had to find the digit sum of something. I used Muhammad Hasan Khan's code, however it kept returning the right number as a recurring decimal, i.e. when the digit sum was 4, i'd get 4.44444444444444 etc.
Hence I edited it, getting the digit sum correct each time with this code:

```
 double a, n, sumD;
 for (n = a; n > 0; sumD += n % 10, n /= 10);
 int sumI = (int)Math.Floor(sumD);
```

where a is the number whose digit sum you want, n is a double used for this process, sumD is the digit sum in double and sumI is the digit sum in integer, so the correct digit sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int SumOfDigits(int num)
{
    string stringNum = num.ToString();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringNum.Length; i++)
    {
      sum+= int.Parse(Convert.ToString(stringNum[i]));

    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to perform specific operations like add odd numbers/even numbers only, add numbers with odd index/even index only, then following code suits best. In this example, I have added odd numbers from the input number.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Input number");
        Console.WriteLine(GetSum(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
    
    public static int GetSum(string num){
        int summ = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < num.Length; i++){
            int currentNum;
            if(int.TryParse(num[i].ToString(),out currentNum)){
                 if(currentNum % 2 == 1){
                    summ += currentNum;
                }
            }
       } 
       return summ;
    }
}
```

Comment: The original question does not ask to sum the odd digits.  Please, consider updating your answer to provide a solution to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest and easiest way would be using loops to [find sum of digits](http://www.codeforwin.in/2015/06/c-program-to-calculate-sum-of-digits.html).

```
int sum = 0;
int n = 1234;

while(n > 0)
{
    sum += n%10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int sum = 0;
    int n;
    printf("Enter ir num ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    printf("Sum of digits is %i\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Surprised nobody considered the Substring method. Don't know whether its more efficient or not. For anyone who knows how to use this method, its quite intuitive for cases like this.

```
string number = "17463";
int sum = 0;
String singleDigit = "";
for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
{
singleDigit = number.Substring(i, 1);
sum = sum + int.Parse(singleDigit);
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```