# Is there a way to convert an integer digits into an array (i.e. 45 -> array[0] = 5 ; array [1] = 4)?

Tags: mips, mips32

Similar to this problem: [convert an integer number into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515612/convert-an-integer-number-into-an-array) but I don't know how this is implemented in MIPS.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. This is not special to MIPS, so try a C version first, once you have that working, then translate to assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is a way. You divide by 10 for every digit in your number and store the remainder in your array. This will probably do the job:

```
.data
array: .word 

.text
.globl main

main:
la $t9, array
li $t1, 45            #number to be stored
li $t2, 10            #base 10

while:
beq $t1, $0, end     

div $t1, $t2        # divide by ten, $hi = $t1/$t2, $lo = $t1 mod $t2
mfhi $t3        
mflo $t1
sw $t3, 0($t9)      #store word into array
addi $t9, $t9, 4    #increment array index
j while
end:
```