# array numbers which sum is dividing on 4

Tags: c#, c++, for-loop

I want to  print numbers on label from 1-to 100

The number's sum must be dividing on 4.

Example:
print 35.  because  3+5 = 8 .
8 dividing on 4.

This is code
from loop printing numbers. but how choose those numbers?
print those numbers from 1 to 100 ;

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
     //select numbers wich sum is dividing on 4
     label3.Text += Convert.ToString(i) + " | ";
}
```

Comment: Answer is in this link [Sum of digits in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478968/sum-of-digits-in-c-sharp) of StackOverflow.

And 8 dividing 4 is 8%4 ==0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stolen from [Greg Hewgill answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/478974/447156), you can use his algorithm and use [remainder operator (`%`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) like;

```
int sum, temp;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
     sum = 0;
     temp = i;
     while (temp != 0)
     {
         sum += temp % 10;
         temp /= 10;
     }

     if (sum % 4 == 0)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
}
```

Result will be;

```
4
8
13
17
22
26
31
35
39
40
44
48
53
57
62
66
71
75
79
80
84
88
93
97
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/hmdlYT)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a nested loop for that , and use the `%` operator (`%` means the rest of division):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
     for (int j = i; j < 100; j++)
     {
           //select numbers wich sum is dividing on 4
           if( (i+j)%4 == 0)
           {
                 label3.Text += Convert.ToString(i) + Convert.ToString(j) " | ";
           }
     }
}
```